# How we can manage Web Server and Application Server in AWS (EC2 instance)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a web application in Spring boot, now I want to deploy it on Server so that our Client application (Angular 4 application) can consume REST services.
Is it good to deploy both application on same server? or do I need to create seperate server for each?

Answer (score 0):

Will you ever need to deploy your applications separately? Will you need to scale one application independently of the other? Do your applications have different security requirements? If so, you should separate your applications to run on separate distinct instances.